# Can i monitor the system audio on windows and possibly analyze it?

Tags: python, audio, twitch

I'm making a chat moderation bot for a friend who streams on twitch.tv and I would like it to perform certain actions when the audio gets to a high level. It would also be incredibly useful to analyze the system audio and compare it to predefined audio files. Is any of this possible, and do libraries exist for this?

Answer (score 1):

The ossaudiodev library might be able to provide the functionality that you need.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/ossaudiodev.html

Specifically, the `oss_mixer_device.get` function returns the volume of a certain mixer control.